# How to vertically and horizontally center a linear layout inside a relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

Been trying to do this for a while, and nothing is working.

I'm trying to vertical and horizontal center a linear layout inside a relative layout.

The point is to get two text-views perfectly centered inside the relative layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:textColor="#ff0fff"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test"
            android:textColor="#ff0fff"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

set attribute `centerInParent` to **true** to center Linear Layout in Relative Layout and `gravity` to **center** TextView in your `LinearLayout`

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center">
```

Comment: Perfect. Works. Thanks.